# How to check if margin-top of one element is equal to height of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the JQuery following code:

```
$(".header").css('margin-top', $("#imgHeading").height());
```

It sets the element with the `header` class's top margin to the height of the element with the `imgHeader` id.

I want to run an if statement which checks if the `header`'s top margin is equal to the `imgHeader`'s height before it runs the actual function.

```
if (/* condition needed here Eg. marginTop != height */) {
    $(".header").css('margin-top', $("#imgHeading").height());
}
```

I just need the condition, struggling to figure out what to do there.

Comment: How are the values obtained? Are they set by Javascript, or by the original styling?

Comment: Just curious, what's the point?:)

Comment: how about this?
`if($(".header").css('margin-top') == $("#imgHeading").height())`

Comment: @IgorDymov I have a boss with very specific requirements :P

Comment: @Kebeng Thanks, that's just what I needed :)

Comment: Wouldn't you only run the function if the margin is NOT already the same as the other div height?  So, `if(!$(".header").css('margin-top') == $("#imgHeading").height()) {//`

Comment: @sideroxylon yeah I gathered that much, I just need to get the individual properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var height = $("#imgHeading").height();
if(parseInt($(".header").css('margin-top'), 10) !== height) {
    $(".header").css('margin-top', height);
}
```

Comment: Why set imgHeading to a variable first though?

Comment: Caching the value to a variable to minimize DOM access and multiple execution of the same statement is considered a good practice. :)

Comment: Yes, but OP mentioned calling this *inside* a function, which will result in a new scope === new variable created every single time. Besides, who says the actual height hasn't been change meanwhile? OP didn't mention *doing* something with the actual `#imgHeading` height.

Comment: Not sure if comparing `.css('margin-top')` to `height()` will work as one will give you a string, e.g. '5px' and the other an integer value.

Comment: Nice point @ChrisHodges Updated my answer to make the right comparison now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should work for everything except IE10 and lower. It works for percentage values too:

`if(getComputedStyle($(".header")[0]).marginTop == getComputedStyle($("#imgHeading")[0]).height)`

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ceL1qnty/)

Comment: This is quite messy, you're basically creating two jQuery objects, grab their original element, and use a vanilla method on those to measure the difference.

Comment: Agreed, it could be prettier. If I've got the time I'll do a more elegant version. The point was to use `getComputedStyle()` rather than comparing jQuery `.css('margin-top')` to `.height()`, since the css value will be a string (e.g. '5px' or '10%') whereas the height() method will return an integer value.

Comment: `parseInt(el.css('margin-top'), 10)` could be of service there.

Comment: Yep, but that still wouldn't work for percentage valued dimensions. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ceL1qnty/1/.

Comment: % automatically get converted to pixel values. as per `console.log($('#imgHeading').height()) console.log(parseInt($('.header').css('margin-top'), 10))`